# How to off session access token expired on facebook api?

Tags: facebook, access-token

I go to https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer to get my photo in facebook, I use this code:

```
$json = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=AAAGRD7DAWfgBAEhuOpVW9OhUg8JVvylV5uA9dB7VCWP5IFfTUg6ktBZCPpsmdf3hBJtxbOsdWFzrCEwFZCMUSdKTCGBZBPdZCIuzbfoOyqW8PC8R6cZCB&fields=photos.limit(14).fields(name,source,picture,link)');
```

to get json, but it's always expired in 2 hours.

Is there any way to set access token never expire?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to get a user token that doesn't expire. Facebook has made this intentional so that users who forget about their installs have them automatically removed from getting access.

You can extend it to two months maximum.

See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/extending-tokens/

Comment: can we get new access token for each 1 hour?